# Why did the image (from fontawesome) move away from the text when I put flex-grow= 1

Tags: html, css

Why did the image (fontawesome) move away from the text when I put `flex-grow= 1;`
Watch this video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hsDeG1RFczXVts75HuPwgktDSFa5iT-3/view?usp=sharing

```css
.srv {
display: flex;
 }
 
i {
  color: #10cab7;;
    flex-basis: 60px;
    flex: 1;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0px;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.6;
    color: #444;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="srv">
                <i class="fas fa-palette fa-2x"></i>
                <div class="text">
                    <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
                    <p>
                        Graphic design is the process of visual communication and problem-solving using one or more of
                        typography, photography and illustration.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS flex, children might have different flex values to be bigger or smaller compared to their siblings, so removing flex property would make its size normal, or if there is a width property, it would use that as size.

Comment: I still don't understand
The image when I gave it `flex-basis: 60px; ` We see that the text is still attached to it, so what is the reason for this?
And also why after giving the text `flex= 1;` the image move away from the text?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Flex is a shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink, and flex-basis; where flex-basis is equivalent to width.

When stable flex-basis: 60px is indicating that the element "i" will have a width of 60px; but when you apply the flex property you are overwriting the flex-basis property.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuU0x.png)

When you only use the Flex-basis.

Flex-grow: 0 Default value
Flex-shrink: 1 Default value.
Flex-basis: 60px

When you use the Flex property: 1.

Flex-grow: 1
Flex-shrink: 1
Flex-basis: 1

The flex-grow property is what makes the element grow.

Comment: I still don't understand. The image when I gave it `flex-basis: 60px;`  We see that the text is still attached to it, so what is the reason for this? And also why after giving the text `flex= 1;` the image move away from the text?